# AngularJS Validation : code working in JSfiddle but not in plunker

Tags: angularjs, validation, jsfiddle, plunker

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saras_arya/f0cwccsj/1/) here and a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/lCVWrTa6bIY0uL9zRvaQ?p=preview) here.
The issue is when I fill all the values correctly the variable `myForm.$valid` is true and hence submit is enabled in jsFiddle but same is not the case in my plunker Why??

Comment: It doesn't work in jsfiddle as well, once you switch to angular 1.4.8

Comment: It works with 1.5.0 here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saras_arya/f0cwccsj/2/)

Comment: Did this help you?

Comment: No it did not... I don't think it was a version problem